# Merge multiple rows having some identity to a new one that have the sum of a column thats is distinct between thems

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this :

```
id    name    qt
----------------
 0      mm     4
 1      mm     5
 2      xx     8
```

I want update it or get new table that will produce this kind of result:

```
id   name     qt
------------------
 0     mm      9 (sum of the two or multiple some identical )
 1     xx      8
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: The `id` column would not make sense in your result set since there are multiple `id` records that are being summed.

Comment: Please undo your last edit. Posting your question as an image is horrible formatting and makes it susceptible to link rot. Posting as text makes it much easier to answer

Answer (score 0):

Including the `id` column will cause the `GROUP BY` to fail since multiple records are being summed that have different `id`s.

```
    SELECT name, SUM(qt) as qt_sum
    FROM table GROUP BY name
```

Comment: my table havn't only this two column , it have other that are identical for the name mm

Comment: Well you need to provide details of what you have and need. the information you provided is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS id
, name
, SUM(qt) AS qt
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

I'm making the assumption that the `id` field doesn't actually mean anything because the id of the record `xx` actually changes between your two visuals. That's why I'm setting it by ROW_NUMBER() so it increments for distinct name. If this isn't the case, remove the ROW_NUMBER() expression and add id to the GROUP BY clause. This does mean that records in the name field may change depending on the number of distinct names.

Comment: what about other column that are identical for the name mm , how i could bring all column of the table

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re  asking

Answer (score 0):

If you really need and id column you could create one like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=66c4b574b5a7d5989e9102cd2e44ddbb)...

```
create table Test (id int, name varchar(10), qt int)

insert into Test values (0, 'mm', 4)
insert into Test values (1, 'mm', 5)
insert into Test values (2, 'xx', 8)

select 
     row_number() over (order by name) - 1
   , name
   , sum(qt) as qt
from Test
group by name
```

There may be some cases where this does not work for you, but with such limited sample data it is hard to tell.